# How to display an image that we received through Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Web server generates images and sends them to client directly. There are no URLs to the images, for security reasons. For example, if I enter `/images/25` URL in the browser server will send it and browser will download it.

Now I want to get this image from Ajax call and then display it on existing page. I can get the image data. My question is: how can I display an image?

```
$.get("/images/25", function (rawImageData) {
   // ??? Need to add an image to DOM
});
```

**Update**

I apologize for being so stupid. Thank you, JW. Of course I can just put img tag with src to my URL. It does not matter if this is a direct URL to an image file or the server sends it dynamically.

Comment: Is the image data returned as `base64`?

Comment: No, as binary, I am just stupid :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So it sounds like there **is** a URL, and it's `/images/25`.

As far as I know, you can't display image data that you get from an AJAX call*. But why not just put the URL in an `<img>` tag? It doesn't matter to the browser that the image is generated by the server, rather than read from a file.

***EDIT:** I was wrong; see gideon's answer if you really need to use an AJAX call (e.g. you need to make a POST request, or send certain headers).

Comment: Why not use the img tag?  Because the image is sensitive and Id rather it be behind authorization to fetch it.  There doesnt seem to be a way to specify an authorization header with the <img> tag

Answer (score 22):

To expand on Matt's answer you could use base64 encoded img urls. This is an [example from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Examples) of what that img tag would look like:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
 AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
 9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

You need a blank image:

```
<img id="target" src="" />
```

Your server needs to return the image as a base64 string, then you could do:

```
$.get("/images/25", function (rawImageData) {
      $("#target").attr("src","data:image/gif;base64," + rawImageData);
});
```

See this [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images) for more in base64 encoded img urls.

I made a short demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/99jAX/1/

Answer (score 5):

You want to send the raw image data [base64-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), combined with the [`data://` URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

Answer (score 2):

Another way you can achieve this is using **Blob** with **ObjectURL**. This way the browser creates a temporary *pseudo* resource with *blob url* to be used as a *src* for the image.

For **jQuery** you need to modify the **get** request a little, telling that you want a **blob** as a response. Otherwise it won't work:

```
$.get({
  url: imgUrl,
  xhrFields: {
    responseType: "blob",
  },
  success: function (blobData) {
    const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blobData);
    $('#imgPlaceholder1').attr('src', objectURL);
  },
});
```

Or you can do it with pure JS:

```
fetch(imgUrl)
.then(response => response.blob())
.then(blob => {
  const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  document.getElementById('imgPlaceholder2').src = objectURL;
});
```

Tested in **Chrome 89.0.4389.114**, **Firefox 65.0.1** and **MS Edge 89.0.774.76**.

Have a look at the working example in the snippet below.

```js
function getImage() {
  const imgUrl = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/19/Crystal_Project_image.png';
  
  // jQuery
  $.get({
    url: imgUrl,
    xhrFields: {
      responseType: "blob",
    },
    success: function(blobData) {
      const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blobData);
      $('#imgPlaceholder1').attr('src', objectURL);
    },
  });

  // Vanilla JS
  fetch(imgUrl)
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(blob => {
      const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      document.getElementById('imgPlaceholder2').src = objectURL;
    });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><button onclick="getImage()">Load image</button></div><br>
<div width="100%">
  <div><img id="imgPlaceholder1" alt="Nothing here yet" /></div>  <br>
  <div><img id="imgPlaceholder2" alt="Nothing here yet" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd bank on it being the same as if you rendered if via PHP or ASP or whatever. just something simple like

```
$('#elementOfChoice').append('<img src="'+ rawImageData +'" alt="something" />');
```

though I could be wrong. All depends on whats happening behind the scenes to make that image become what it is. If its gotta pass through a PHP file cause its a base_64 image and needs to be encoded, or whatever the case then that has to be done accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

```
$( "<img>" ).attr( "src", icon_url ).appendTo( "#images" );
```