# Displaying the image returned from FileResponse (fastapi) on a webpage using ajax

Tags: python, ajax, fastapi

I am raising a GET request using ajax, to my api. The api returns an image and some other information back (information i want to send). I am sending the image using FileResponse function of fastapi. What I am not getting is how to display the image sent from the api on the wbepage. I am looking for the javascript for displaying the image sent through FileResponse.
The return statement from the api:

```
return {'img_src':FileResponse(Path_to_the_image), 'Tables':output_dic}
```

The html side code:

```
$.ajax({ 
                    url: URL for api,   
                    type: 'get', 
                    dataType : "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function(response){
            I am using the contents of response here
 }
```

I am able to successfully use the contents of 'Tables', that is being returned along with the image but I don't know how display the image that is sent. Can someone please tell me how I could do this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511302/how-to-display-an-image-that-we-received-through-ajax-call