# Using an AJAX call to display base64 image data via PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, base64

I'm wanting to render an image using an AJAX call but I’m having trouble returning an image from the server as a base24 string via PHP.

In the renderImage function below the test image data 'R0lGODlhCw...' is displaying correctly but the image data coming from the AJAX call is not.

I want to use AJAX instead of just outputting the image file contents into the src attribute because I eventually want to add authorization headers to the PHP file.

I think I’m missing something in the PHP file and some headers in the ajax call?

**PHP file: image.php**

```php
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
$id = $_GET["id"];
$file = '../../upload/'.$id;
$type = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($file);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
return $base64;
?>
```

**JS**

```js
function renderImage(id) {
//return "R0lGODlhCwALAIAAAAAA3pn/ZiH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAALAAsAAAIUhA+hkcuO4lmNVindo7qyrIXiGBYAOw==";
 return $.ajax({
    url: '[server URL]/image.php',
    data:{"id":id},
    type: 'GET',
  });
};

$('.feedImage').each(async function() {
  try {
    const res = await renderImage($(this).data("id"));
    $(this).attr("src","data:image/gif;base64," + res);
  } catch(err) {
    console.log("error"+err);
  }
});
```

raw image obtained from [How to display an image that we received through Ajax call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511302/how-to-display-an-image-that-we-received-through-ajax-call)

Comment: You may make a mistake here. The response from the server starts with ```'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,'``` and ```"data:image/gif;base64,"``` is also prepended to ```src``` in client side.

Comment: You should also `echo $base64;` from your PHP (unless there's other code not shown that does that already)

Comment: In your `image.php` change this line `$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);`
 `return $base64;` to this `$base64 = base64_encode($data);
echo $base64;` then catch it with your ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should fix your php image rendering

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
$id = $_GET["id"];
$file = '../../upload/'.$id;
$type = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($file);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
echo json_encode(array('id' => $base64));
?>
```

Then your javascript, as you already defined the data image type there is no need to repeat it on the javascript.

```
function renderImage(id) {
//return "R0lGODlhCwALAIAAAAAA3pn/ZiH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAALAAsAAAIUhA+hkcuO4lmNVindo7qyrIXiGBYAOw==";
 return $.ajax({
    url: '[server URL]/image.php',
    data:{"id":id},
    type: 'GET',
  });
};

$('.feedImage').each(async function() {
  try {
    const res = await renderImage($(this).data("id"));
    $(this).attr("src", res);
  } catch(err) {
    console.log("error"+err);
  }
});
```

Comment: this was a great solution. I just had to remove the json encoding from the echo call -> ```echo $base64;``` and it worked a treat. Thank you!