# How can I convert the response coming from the api to image

Tags: javascript

I have response coming from the api like attached image. I want to convert this response to the image. I have tried to convert this into base64 string but i am not able to do it as well.

Image of the response

[image]

api is like this:

```
          axios.get(`https://api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/tadigital/v1/employees/2223/photo/large`, 
                { auth: {
                    username: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                    password: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
                  }
                }
                ).then(resp => {
                  console.log(resp.data)
          });
```

I want the solution without using responseType in the get request because api is not accepting the response type. I am not getting a way to convert this to image

Comment: We can't see what the responded data looks like because the username and password provided is incorrect. I am not saying you should share the credentials just show as an example of what the responded data looks like

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display an image that we received through Ajax call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511302/how-to-display-an-image-that-we-received-through-ajax-call)

Comment: @seriously seriously? It's inside image attached to question

Comment: @Justinas he/she said they already tried base64

Comment: @Justinas the attached image is not a buffer...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want the solution without using responseType in the get request because api is not accepting the response type.

[`responseType`](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config) has nothing to do with server. It tells Axios how to handle the expected response data. In this scenario you could pass `responseType: "blob"`, which can be passed to [`URL.createObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) to create an URL that can be used as `<img>` `src`.

```
const url = 'https://api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/tadigital/v1/employees/2223/photo/large';
axios.get(url, {
  auth: {
    username: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    password: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  },
  responseType: 'blob',
}).then((resp) => {
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(resp.data);
  img.alt = 'employee photo';

  document.body.append(img);
});
```

```js
const url = "data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9Ii0xMS41IC0xMC4yMzE3NCAyMyAyMC40NjM0OCI+CiAgPHRpdGxlPlJlYWN0IExvZ288L3RpdGxlPgogIDxjaXJjbGUgY3g9IjAiIGN5PSIwIiByPSIyLjA1IiBmaWxsPSIjNjFkYWZiIi8+CiAgPGcgc3Ryb2tlPSIjNjFkYWZiIiBzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg9IjEiIGZpbGw9Im5vbmUiPgogICAgPGVsbGlwc2Ugcng9IjExIiByeT0iNC4yIi8+CiAgICA8ZWxsaXBzZSByeD0iMTEiIHJ5PSI0LjIiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDYwKSIvPgogICAgPGVsbGlwc2Ugcng9IjExIiByeT0iNC4yIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgxMjApIi8+CiAgPC9nPgo8L3N2Zz4K";

axios.get(url, {
  responseType: "blob",
}).then((resp) => {
  const img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(resp.data);
  img.alt = "React icon";
  
  document.body.append(img);
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/axios@1/dist/axios.js"></script>
```

Note that you should call [`URL.revokeObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL) if you no longer need the URL.

Comment: Oh this worked, I was passing responseType before auth. But I tried same as yours and it worked. Thanks

Comment: It shouldn't matter if you pass `responseType` before or after `auth`, as long as you do NOT pass it IN `auth`.

Comment: I passed it outside of auth 

Comment: I have one more issue with the cors one: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.". How can we solve this issue. In local I was using the cors unblock extension for test purpose.

Comment: @user17320926 If you have access to the server that is delivering the images, make sure the Access-Control-Allow-Origin is present for the response. If you don't have access to the server you can setup a proxy. Let your JavaScript send a request to your own server, then do the external request from the server and forward the response back to your front-end. See [XMLHttpRequest cannot load XXX No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/3982562) for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

1 Encoding should be base64 you can do that on either on the server or the client.

2 The Raw data should be set as the following -

```
    <img ng-src="data:image/*;base64,{{Raw Binary Data}}"/>
```

Comment: By doing this it is directly adding the data to the src tag, the data which I have shared in the question in image

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the server is sending raw data
You can convert it to blob by using fetch like below:

```
const res = await fetch(url);
const data = await res.blob();
const image = URL.createObjectURL(data);
```

Set `Image` as `src` of an image tag